# Java print items in tree map list

Tags: java, treemap

I currently have a TreeMap of the form `<String, List<List<String>>`

I'm trying to write my tree map to an output file where I get the inner values of my string[] all separated by a colon.

Do I need a second for loop to loop through each inner list and format it using a `.join(":", elements)`?

Or is there a more concise way to keep it all in a single for loop statement?

I've tried a few things and my current code is:

```
new File(outFolder).mkdir();
File dir = new File(outFolder);
//get the file we're writing to
File outFile = new File(dir, "javaoutput.txt");
//create a writer
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile), "utf-8"))) { 
  for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : allResults.entrySet()) {
    writer.write(entry.getKey() + ", "+ Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()).replace("null", "").toString());
    writer.newLine();   
  }
```

**Current output:**

> ANY, [[469, 470], [206, 1013, 1014], [2607, 2608]]

**Desired output:**

> ANY, 469:470, 206:1013:1014, 2607:2608

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you loop through the arrays and print them accordingly?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to build the string to your desired output. Then use `writer.write(stringBuilder.toString())`.

Comment: Could you also provide test input? E.g. when putting values to map like allResults.put("test1", new String[]{"1", "2", "3"});
should be output be "test1, 1:2:3" or something else?

Comment: Use second inner loop and format as you like.

Comment: @Daniil Sure, a bit more background is that there are 3 indexes in the inner list values can get placed into, all depending on which input file it comes from. 

Sample input: this[1] 
Would be placed into a single index of the tree map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.join(":", arr)` can be used to take the String array and return a colon-separated String.   This can then be used with Streams with a Collector to join these strings with a comma-separator, so :

```
TreeMap<String, String[]> allResults = new TreeMap<>();
allResults.put("a", new String[]{"469", "470"});
allResults.put("b", new String[]{"206", "1013", "1014"});
allResults.put("c", new String[]{"2607", "2608"});

String result = allResults.entrySet().stream()
                  .map(e -> String.join(":", e.getValue()))
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(result);
```

produces :

```
469:470, 206:1013:1014, 2607:2608
```

With a `List<List<String>>`, you need a stream within a stream, so :

```
    TreeMap<String, List<List<String>>> allResults = new TreeMap<>();
    allResults.put("a", Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("469", "470"), Arrays.asList("206", "1013", "1014"), Arrays.asList("2607", "2608")));
    allResults.put("b", Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("169", "470")));
    allResults.put("c", Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("269", "470")));

    String result = allResults.entrySet().stream()
                      .map(i -> i.getKey() + "," + i.getValue().stream().map(elements -> String.join(":", elements))
                                      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                                      )
                      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    System.out.println(result);
```

which produces :

```
a,469:470, 206:1013:1014, 2607:2608
b,169:470
c,269:470
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it gives me the output of '[1,2]:[1,3]:null' where it is separating each list in my list by a colon and my values are still separated by a comma inside the brackets.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to show the complete setup and results, based on the text in the question - which was an array in a Map, so I'm not sure where "each list in my list" comes in;  that sounds like you are saying that the TreeMap is a `<String, List<List<String>>` ??

Comment: @racraman Sorry. You're correct, my tree map is `<String, List <List<String>>` I.e : `Word, [[1,2],[1,3],null]` I've updated my original post. I misunderstood how to write my format.

Comment: No worries - just updated my answer for those types.